# Define worksheet name depends on variable

Tags: vba, excel

```
For i = 1 To n
    Sheets(2).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "SheetName(i)"
Next
```

Here I want to define sheetName depends on variable "i". For example, when i = 1, name should be SheetName1 . Can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long: n = Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To n
        Worksheets(i).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).name = "SheetName" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

What I have used:

- You are speaking about `Worksheets`, but you are using `Sheets`. There is a  difference between these two. `Sheets` include `Worksheets` and `Charts`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `"SheetName(i)"` use `"SheetName" & i"`, try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    For i = 1 To n
        Sheets(2).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "SheetName" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```